# Select a line or lines in Vim [shift+v] and then press :

Tags: vim

If I select a line and then press `:`, the cursor correctly allows me to type in a command, but it fills the command bar with `:'<,'>`, so I have to delete back to the colon to type in, eg `FormatLines`.

Is there a line I can put in my vimrc to prevent the garbage `'<,'>` from appearing?

Comment: what do you mean garbage? That means apply the  command to the selection.

Comment: @aioobe I was wondering about that. But there are accepted vim questions on SO.

Comment: @aioobe It does say "off topic unless it's about tools primarily used for coding," so they maybe need to reword guidance about what is allowed here.

Comment: @wrhall, it seems like the consensus is that vim-questions [do belong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-do-they-belong-to-stack-overflow-or-super-user) here on stackoverflow. My bad. Sorry for the close-vote. Hopefully people see this comment and avoid voting to close. (Original comments removed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not garbage. This `'<,'>` is a range equal to the visual selection. Most ex commands in Vim (those commands starting with `:`, such as your `FormatLines` command) operate on a range. This automatic range is telling Vim to run your command on the selected lines.

I'd guess, if you removed this range, your `:FormatLines` command probably operates either only on the current line, or on the entire file, unless you get the range in a weird way within the command itself.

If you actually do not want this automatic range, you simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to remove it. But you don't want to do that automatically, because otherwise doing things like "run a search/replace on the visual selection" (`:'<,'>s/pattern/replacement`) or "run a command on the selected lines" (`:'<,'>g/^/MyCommand`) won't work unless you add the range manually, which is a much bigger pain than getting rid of it manually on the rare occasions where you need to do that.

Answer (score 3):

`'<,'>` means, "From the first line or character of the last selected Visual area in the current buffer to the last line or character of the last selected Visual area in the current buffer."

So it's not "garbage", it means that the command you enter after the `:` will execute on the selected line. It's even more useful when you select multiple lines.

If you just want call a command *on the current line*, don't enter Visual mode, just hit <kbd>:</kbd> and it will operate on the current line.

See:

- [`:help '<`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#'<)
- [`:help '>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#'>)
- [`:help visual-use`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#Visual)
- [`:help :`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:)

Answer (score 3):

The `'<` and `'>` marks represent the start and end lines of your visual selection. Many command can take a range of lines like `:s`. Thus when you enter command mode via `:` from visual mode, Vim helps you out by supplying the visual mode range.

If you do not want the this range you can use `<esc>` before you press `:` to go back to normal mode. Or you can press `<c-u>` while on the command line to clear the line. Personally I would suggest you get in the habit of exiting visual mode when you do not specifically need it.

For more help see:

```
:h '>
:h range
```